# Debugging Devise w/ Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there anyway to display the queries that Devise is generating when trying to log the user in? There seems to be no output of this in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

These queries are in the same place as all other queries: your `log` folder. `tail` the files in this directory to view the queries.

Comment: No it's not. See http://grab.by/8Wql for a screenshot of my terminal window which is tailing the development.log file. I'm getting a "Invalid username & password" flash message from Devise so I know it's executing a query but it's not displaying it.